# Obtaining Counts by Column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, boolean

I have a df with several boolean columns, here is an excerpt:

```
 L1 MATCH  L2 MATCH  L3 MATCH  L4 MATCH  L5 MATCH  
0  True      True      True      False    False  
1  True      True      False     False    False  
2  True      True      True      True     False  
3  True      False     True      True     False  
4  True      True      False     True     False
```

I would like to obtain the counts of True vs False for each of those columns as follows (or similar). If easier, I would take the transpose of the below as well.

```
             True       False
L1 MATCH     12345      6789
L2 MATCH     12345      6789
L3 MATCH     12345      6789
L4 MATCH     12345      6789
L5 MATCH     12345      6789
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `pd.concat` and `sum`:

```
pd.concat([df.sum(),(~df).sum()], axis=1, keys=['True','False'])
```

Output:

```
          True  False
L1 MATCH     5      0
L2 MATCH     4      1
L3 MATCH     3      2
L4 MATCH     3      2
L5 MATCH     0      5
```

Comment: vere elegant and simple, I love one line solutions!

Comment: yeah, this is very elegant!